# Issue with converting string to Carbon date objects in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project where I'm sending date values as object of string type from my frontend using AJAX and trying to convert them to Carbon date objects in my controller

package used. - > https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar

frontend code

```
 var startDate = $('.effective_period_start_date').val();
        var endDate = $('.effective_period_end_date').val();

        if (startDate && endDate) {
            // Prepare the data to send to the server
            // var data = {// Include CSRF token
                
            //     "effective_period_start_date": startDate,
            //     "effective_period_end_date": endDate
            // };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
                }, 
                data: {
                    effective_period_start_date: startDate,
                    effective_period_end_date: endDate
                },
```

```
CONTROLLER


$startDate = $request->effective_period_start_date;
$endDate = $request->effective_period_end_date;
              
$startDateObject = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $startDate);
$endDateObject = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $endDate);
$Userdescription = 'Event description';
$event = Event::create([
'startDateTime' => $startDateObject,
'endDateTime' => $endDateObject,
'description' => $Userdescription
]);
$event->save();
```

I'm getting an "Array to string conversion" error at the line where I try to create Carbon date objects. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps and inspect what's happening:

1. Write `console.log(startDate, endDate);` inside your JS code and look at what you are sending back.
2. In the browser's developer tools, check the Network tab to see the actual payload being sent to the server. Ensure that the date values are not being sent as arrays.
3. In your Laravel controller, dump your values with `dd($request->all());` code.

You can share the results of these steps with me so that I can help you better.